# HTML dropdown arrow? What am I doing wrong? D:

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select, mybb

I've created a new select style for use in certain pages, while this works fine I'm struggling to get the dropdown arrow to show. I'm trying to display an arrow from a font (font loads and is fine, issue is how I'm trying to get it working)

The below is an example of one of the dropdowns I've got on a page, right now there's no arrow at all being displayed.

```css
/** dropdown styling **/

.selectadmin {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #666;
  background: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/** dropdown arrow **/

.selectadmin:before {
  font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
  content: ';';
  position: absolute;
  right: 9px;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 235%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}


/** dropdown arrow **/

.selectadmin:after {
  font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
  content: ':';
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 120%;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td width="40%" class="trow2admin"><strong><span class="admintitle">Selection:</span></strong></td>
  <td width="60%" class="trow2admin"><select class="selectadmin" ; style="width:48%" ;>
       <option value="default">General</option>
       <option value="1">One</option>
       <option value="2">Two</option>
       <option value="3">Three</option>
       <option value="4">Four</option>
       <option value="5">Five/option>
        <option value="6">Six</option>
       </td>
    </select>
</tr>
```

Help would definitely be appreciated, I tried wrapping  but it didn't work at all. All It did was create a non-workable copy of the dropdown style, no font arrow either.

Comment: did you try to add `position:relative` to the .selectadmin class

Comment: You have errors (extraneous semicolons in the select start tag; end tags the wrong way round) but I'm not sure that causes the problem. Would adding `appearance:none` (with the proper prefixes) help any?

Comment: @PullataPraveen - Adding it made the arrow show, (on a dropdown that has the selectadmin tags round it, it shows how it should but it isn't clickable.) - With no tags around it the dropdown arrow is to the left. https://i.imgur.com/zxBhkQ3.png https://i.imgur.com/DiMtwSH.png

Comment: can you add the code with font url in jsfiddle so that i can check your code in testing page @BK1

Comment: @PullataPraveen https://jsfiddle.net/bdt39hnk/ Here you go. The fonts aren't loading for me on the website but the font-face urls are definitely accurate.

Comment: @BK1 as per your fiddle. you did not coded a styling to the `select` tag. Please check out once the styling is coded to the parent of `select` i.,e  `<div class="selectadmin ">` Please try to provide full information and do not write a PHP coding in a js.fiddle try to make simple one to make result rather of adding a complex code..

Answer (score 0):

It's quite likely that the problem is the use of pseudo elements on a `select` tag - I don't think that's possible.

As a workaround, try wrapping the `select` in an extra `div`, and then moving the `before` and `after` on to that element.